# spring and aspectj, intercept method of a non-proxy object

Tags: java, spring, proxy, aspectj

i want to intercept method from a non-proxied object.

I have a class instance `MyClass myClassInstance=new MyClass()` and i want to intercept call of `myClassInstance` methods.

I know all works good with proxies, but i need aspect on non proxied.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, but it is not desirable.

You can use `@Configurable` and AspectJ will intercept calls. Read [the 7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring section of the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) about it.

In short - AspectJ plugs some "magic" either compile-time or load-time (with a respective weaver), which modifies the classes so that they become part of the spring context.

As of why I think it is undesirable - this is dark magic that happens by modifying the classes' structure. It's not an object-oriented approach, and I think it will be hard to support. Imagine 6 months later a colleague of yours is debugging a nasty issue. It could take days before he realizes this magic is happening. This opinion is subjection though. The functionality is there and if you need it - use it.

Comment: @Bozho: I annotate MyClass with @Configurable but nothing is intercepted.

Comment: @blow you have to add some more configuration. Like <context-spring... /> - as I said, read the section in the docs. As far as I recall, you'll need either a aspectj compiler, or aspectJ JVM agent

Comment: @Bozho: ok i read now your edit, so i think this is not the solution for me. I wanted intercept call of method of my entities, to manage session for load of lazy collections. This is not the right solution i think.

Comment: Oh, that better be done around the service layer (or dao layer)

Comment: I know, but is annoying write a method every time i need to use a lazy properties of my entity. Sometime i get an entity in application layer(using service layer of course) and after use its properties that can be lazy some times...

Comment: I'm using spring +  hibernate for a desktop application, not a web app, so is OpenSessionInView a solutions for me?

Comment: well, this has gone beyond the scope of the current question. I can ask another one, providing more details

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring, I do not believe so ([I appear to be wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212987/spring-and-aspectj-intercept-method-of-a-non-proxy-object/4213022#4213022)), using AspectJ I believe you can as long as you [compile all the code with the AspectJ compiler](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/implementation.html#d0e7271). However I have never tried it.

Comment: I used Spring 3.0 together with aspectJ compile time weaving, and it worked well. Much better than the proxy approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable load time weaving in Spring.  Then the class loader will weave whatever aspects you define into your classes when they are loaded - regardless of whether they are being created by Spring.

You'll need to enable LTW by adding this line to your context file:

See:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07s08.html#aop-aj-ltw